# Set Width of TextBlock to Screen size in XAML UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, screen-size

I have some textblocks included in a scroll viewer. I don't want to use the horizontal scrollbar so I came up with this idea but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Take a look at the TextWrapping Property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Screen size as the immediate window or page or just view of whatever in XAML you can easily bind the TextBlock.Width to the ActualWidth of that hosting element.

If you're talking about the actual monitor screen size then you just need to create a ViewModel with that property exposed and then bind that the same way.

If you need code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock) has a property called [TextWrapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.textwrapping.aspx). This will allow you the data in your `TextBlock` Not to overflow but increase the Height of `TextBlock` Itself. Also make sure to set `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`.